# Passport.js : How can I avoid serializing and deserializing users?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, passport.js

I am using Passport.js and Angular for a webapp.  I want to use passport.js to help with authentication but I am not using sessions. I get a `[Error: Failed to serialize user into session]` every time I authorize a user.

I tried to add `serializeUser` and `deserializeUser` callback. This did nothing and I still get an error.

Do I have to include `passport-session` and just set something in the session so as to have passport.js authorize the user or can I set `serialize: false` somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why yes this is possible!

From the [documentation](http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/):

> in some cases, session support is not necessary. For example, API
>   servers typically require credentials to be supplied with each
>   request. When this is the case, session support can be safely disabled
>   by setting the session option to false.

```
app.get('/api/users/me',
  passport.authenticate('basic', { session: false }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.json({ id: req.user.id, username: req.user.username });
  });
```

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this answer? It's very clear and answers the question perfectly.